# Using tar to only backup specific folders

Tags: backup, tar

I only want to backup the following folders with my tar command:

```
/var/www
/home/myuser/importantFiles
/home/myuser/anotherFolder
```

And I want these folders to be backed up in the very same .tar.gz archive, how can I achieve this? Do I *really* have to use --exclude to set it to every other folder that I don't want backed up?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Nevermind, I was overlooking the obvious by simply doing this:

```
tar -cvpzf backup.tar.gz /var/www /home/myuser/importantFiles /home/myuser/anotherFolder
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also add specific folders as identified via the find command. For example:

```
tar -cvpf backup.tgz $(find /var/ -name 'www' -o -name 'important')
```